# Masking specific pattern from bitset

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Let there be a bitset represented by an int. Encoded into the bitset are values ranging from 0-15 in the following pattern 0x0f0f0f0f. How can I "push these individual values together" after I mask the bitset with the aforementioned pattern as a bitmask.  e.g.

```
   1111 0001 1111 0001 1111 0001 1111 0001
-> 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 
-> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001 0001 0001
```

**EDIT**:

```
int bits = 0xf1f1f1f1;
int bit_mask = 0x0f0f0f0f;

// my_values == 0x01010101
int my values = bits & bit_mask;

// how can I turn my_values from 0x01010101 to 0x00001111 ?
```

Comment: Post some code. Question is also unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the bits you're interested in and shift them right. You can mask the bits you need at the same time, so there is no need to apply your bitmask first. Something like...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print_int_bits(uint32_t value)
{
    for (uint32_t i=sizeof(uint32_t )*8-1;i>=0;--i)
        std::cout << ((1 << i) & value ? "1" : "0");
    std::cout << std::endl; 
}

int main() {
    // int mask  = 0x0f0f0f0f; not needed
    uint32_t value = 0b11110001111100011111000111110001;
    //value &= mask; not needed, masked in the loop
    uint32_t result = 0;
    for(uint32_t i=0;i<4;++i)
        result |= ((value & (0b00001111 << (i*8))) >> i*4);

    print_int_bits(result);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/aYfqT1)

Comment: Please use uint32_t for 32bit bit sets. Next someone will try this on their arduino where int is 16bit and wonder why it fails.